# Proper breaker for my table saw

Tags: electrical

[image][image]Can I run this motor on a 30 amp breaker? The saw Is "prewired 230v" but the wire from the motor to the plug is only 14 guage. Is that a hazard?

Comment: Does this circuit power anything else, or is it dedicated to this saw?

Comment: is dedicated to the saw. 30 amp 2 pole breaker run with 10/2 w/ground to outlet

Comment: Does the tablesaw have some sort of motor overload protector on it already?

Comment: Not that I know of how. How would I be able to tell?

Comment: @ziggy -- there should be mention in the manual of how the motor's protected. Barring that, I'd check the components labeled T1-T3 on the diagram for labeling that would indicate what they are

Comment: @ziggy -- were you able to figure out if there's an overload protector built into your tablesaw?  For that matter, can you post the model number for the saw?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to start by answering the easy questions first.

The #14 installed by the motor manufacturer is alright. Since manufactures are not regulated by the NEC but by an entirely different set of rules and regulations. JET is a pretty common manufacturer and I feel fairly safe that they are doing the right thing.

NEC Article 430.7(A)(13) states the if a motor is thermally protected is will be labeled as such or have the designation TP on the nameplate. So according to your picture it is not protected. Also your schematic does not show overloads.

Now the circuit design. To start the nameplate shows and amperage of 14.5 but it also shows a KW of 2.2 which translates to 9.5 amps and it doesn't show an efficiency rating. So to be on the safe side I would use the rating found in NEC Table 430.248 which states to use 17 amps as a full load current. By code we add 25% for startup (NEC Article 430.24) so that makes it 21.25 amps. So we can size the conductors for a 30A circuit which would be a #10 conductors.

The overcurrent protection which I assume is a molded case circuit breaker is calculated a little different. the "K" designation on the nameplate is a *Locked-rotor Code Letter* and it gives us a rating from NEC Table 430.7(B) which basically states that if your saw blade locks up it can surge to around 117 amps. Keep in mind there is a duration on this limit. It might be so quick, 1/120th of a second, you won't be able to detect it. This could happen when your blade hits a knot and surges to cut it. So we don't want that to trip the breaker. NEC Article 430.52 and Table 430.52 allow us to increase the size of the overcurrent protection to compensate for this surging. You have to match your delay trip with your surge in order to prevent nuisance tripping.

Most electricians on site are not going to go through the calcs I just gave you. What they are going to do is to install a 30A circuit and protect it with a 40A breaker and call it good unless you start having a problem.

In conclusion, installing a #10 conductor and 30A breaker would be OK. If you started tripping the breaker while cutting certain lumber you are allowed to increase the breaker at least one size maybe two but I wouldn't go any further without consulting a professional in your area.

It's important to remember that **these rules apply only to motor circuits not mixed circuits**. For a DIY only install one piece of equipment on one circuit to stay safe. Also the **overcurrent protection is designed to protect the motor circuit, not the piece of equipment itself.** You might want to install some sort of disconnect or switch with thermal overloads by the saw itself.

Hope this answers some question you might have and stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

Was it a factory supplied plug?  Appliance cords operate under UL authority not NEC, and ampacity is often higher since they are open to air and not packed in blown insulation.

Are you *sure* the saw's instructions and labeling call out a 30A circuit?  I would not be surprised if they wanted a lower breaker size, such as 20A. If so, just change the breaker, the wire in the wall is fine.

Generally a load of this size is fused with a 20A breaker, unless a particular rule is being applied which allows a bump to 25A or 30A on 12AWG wire.  The manual will say.

Comment: it was not a factory supplied plug. it had a 20amp plug and the previous owner claimed he was running it off a 40amp breaker (I assume he was misremembering). I added the schematic to the original post if that helps. it's a 3hp saw

Comment: i had wired my dedicated circuit for 30 amps because that what was recommended to me but when i went to put the new plug on the saw wire and realized it was 14gauge that's when i became skeptical

Comment: Motor rating says 14.5 - I think 15 would be too close for comfort even without the continuous derate.

Comment: I'll bet part of the confusion is that the diagram is for 5 HP **and** 3 HP. If the nameplate 3 HP is 14.5 A (--> 20 A breaker) then 5 HP would be ~ 24 A (--> 30 A breaker).

Comment: So the plug can be 14 gauge? Is that because it's short and doesn't have a lot of resistance ond can dissipate heat easily? Are wire sizes set by a minimum length like 14 gauge uses a 15 amp breaker at 100' but technically a 5' peice of 14 gauge wire could handle 30 amps comfortably?

Comment: @manassehkatz except 14.5A@240V is awfully high for 3hp.  Horses are only 750W after all. I suspect real running amperage is more like 10A.

Comment: @JoeFala because it is in the open where it'll cool better than in a wall, plus you will notice and deal with it if it has a problem.  Definitely do not do that with in-wall wiring!   The weird physics of motors is why we're even putting 30A and 14AWG in the same sentence.  If it were a heater, heck no!

Comment: @Harper would it be fair to say that inductive loads generate less heat on the power supply than resistive loads given the same current draw? Or is it a duty cycle effect? I'd never undesize a wire, I'm just curious. I've actually replaced several cords on tools with larger gauge wire because I feel them getting hot.

Comment: I agree (real ~ 10A), but then where does NEC Table 430.248, which Retired Master Electrician references to come up with 17 A, get that from? Unless that is really including startup and/or continuous load? I just don't see how we get from ~ 10A on up to 30A (or even 40A that Retired Master Electrician suggests)

Comment: @manassehkatz - Table 430.248 doesn't really come up with 17A it simply tells us that we can use it in our calculations. Agreed it covers a wide birth of efficiency and other sins which can cause the problems. The NEC does say you can use the nameplate rating of the motor but you do have to size it plus 25% for startup. So a 14.5A load cannot go on a 15A breaker or a #14 wire. I have always believed that when in doubt you use the maximum sizing allowed not the minimum. It saves time and money form reinstalling it a second time.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician Thanks for the additional info. It just sounds to me like you would take *in this case* 14.5 A * 1.25 = 18.125 A ==> 20 A, and not go larger than that.

Comment: @manassehkatz - I think I would say don't go any smaller than that. Your sizing would be legal per the NEC. Motor circuits are one of the few exceptions where the NEC allows you to over size a breaker to keep it from tripping during start up and short rises in amperage under load. If you installed a 20A circuit and it wasn't tripping under load, then "yahoo go for it", but if the breaker kept tripping it would be fairly easy and legal to increase it to a 25A or even a 30A breaker.